# Maneiras de colocar um site dentro de outro?

Tags: html, iframe

Estou estudando a tag `iframe` do HTML5, vi que com ele podemos colocar sites e videos dentro de uma página. Porém, fiz alguns teste, com arquivos PHP e HTML. A única maneira que **deu certo aparecer o site que eu queria foi no arquivo .html e no navegador Edge..** Qual a melhor maneira de implentar sites dentro de outro?

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito ampla. `iframes` tem inúmeras funções, e não apenas "colocar um site dentro de outro"... Se seu "teste" deu certo apenas no Edge, seu código tem problemas. A propósito, `iframe`é algo antigo e não pertence ao HTML5. Boa sorte amigão!

Comment: `IFRAME` html5?

Comment: Qual alternativa você aconselha para esse tipo de implementação

Comment: já utilizei o load() do jquery.[ http://api.jquery.com/load/ ]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que você quer é incluir um site qualquer dentro do seu. Para isso, a tag `iframe` deve resolver implementada assim:

```
<iframe width="1024" height="768" src="http://www.bbc.com" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);"></iframe>
```

E com algo assim:

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 624px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
iframe {
    position: absolute;            
    top: -95px;
    left: -25px;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
}
```

```html
Site externo ao meu:
<div>
    <iframe src="http://www.bbc.com/" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Funciona melhor [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/CnMCV/1503/), pois o Stack não permite a abertura do site da BBC.

Comment: Seria melhor colocar como código somente, já que os *stack snippets* não permitem o uso de iframes.